# Extract detected objects and save to different images - OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, mser

I have this image:

[image]

and I want to extract all the buttons and save them in different images. Until now I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Rita\\Desktop\\ISCTE\\2_ano\\Tese\MSER\\1_Exemplo\\botoes.PNG',1)

vis = img.copy()
mser = cv2.MSER_create()
vis = img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

regions, _ = mser.detectRegions(gray)

hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
cv2.polylines(vis, hulls, 1, (0, 255, 0))



for i, contour in enumerate(hulls):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.imwrite('1_exemplo_{}.png'.format(i), img[y:y+h,x:x+w])
```

But it's not separate in the correct way. Does anybody know what i'm missing here in the code? Or what it's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different parameters that you have to try in order to extract what you need.

Using the snippet below I extracted all but one blob:

```
mser = cv2.MSER_create( _min_area = 5000, _max_variation = 1.0)
```

[image]

Try varying the other parameters from [THIS LINK](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_features2d.MSER.html) for better results.

Comment: But with that extraction that you did, are you able to save for example button "Habitação" in an image and then button "Climatização" in another image?

Comment: Yes I was able to save 4 of them except the block in the center (Seguranca)

Comment: Can you tell me how you did that? Can you show me your code? Is it similar to mine?

Comment: Yes, instead of this line `mser = cv2.MSER_create()` I added some parameters to select the most relevant blobs using `mser = cv2.MSER_create( _min_area = 5000, _max_variation = 1.0)`. You can find out more about the other parameters [HERE](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_features2d.MSER.html)

Comment: Ok, i've tested and it worked. But initially i had
mser = cv2.MSER_create()

and i could recognize all the buttons.
So, why my loop doesn't work? :S

thanks for your help!